# How can I modify this database to allow collections of files with a folder structure like games for example?

Tags: database, database-design

How can I modify this database to allow collections of files with a folder structure like games for example?

I'm thinking about the database for a [media wiki](https://codeberg.org/LifeSymbiont/media_wiki#project-idea) to store metadata for all media types. I want to include the option to add metadata for games but I don't know how to express it. Games may contain many files and directories. I want users to rate this kind of media as a whole instead of rating every file. The same entity could be used for torrents or software, so rather than just games I want to express something that encompass all those.

When users press on a link to this collection instead of the metadata they see a folder structure containing all the files and if a file is a media file itself users can click on it to go to that file's metadata. So for a torrent if it includes a file in the database you could see the metadata but for a game that has many files no one cares about it would only show the name but it wouldn't allow clicking on it to see more metadata.

https://lemmy.ml/pictrs/image/0f90486c-7c63-4389-93ba-c808fb745ef7.png

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320052/266284) Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Please in code questions give a [mre]. Show what you are able to do. [ask] [Help]

Comment: What is your 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re how/where you are 1st stuck in what published presentation of what design method?